# Unable to make UILabel text glow

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel

I'm running the following code in viewDidLoad,  it is applying the glow outside the label not on the text. Please advise. 
[image: Label]

```
     lbl_score.font = myfont;
     lbl_score.alpha = 1.0;
     lbl_score.textColor = UIColor.greenColor;
     lbl_score.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
     lbl_score.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
     lbl_score.layer.shadowRadius = 30.0f;
     lbl_score.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;
     lbl_score.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

I've imported QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h".  I would like to apply the glow only on the label text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To apply a glow to the actual text in a label, you have to override `drawTextInRect` on the label itself. You're setting a shadow on the label's layer, which is a rectangle.

The override is quite simple. You just adjust the graphics context, call super, then restore the graphics context:

```
-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 30.0, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a shadow on the layer, which is rectangular. `UILabel` has `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset` properties which you should use instead. You can’t set a separate opacity for the shadow this way, but you can bake it into the `UIColor` that you pass for the shadow color.

```
 lbl_score.font = myfont;
 lbl_score.alpha = 1.0;
 lbl_score.textColor = UIColor.greenColor;
 lbl_score.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
 lbl_score.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

Unfortunately, you can’t set a shadow radius in this way. If you need to change the radius, look at doing your own custom drawing in `-drawRect:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found code similar to jrturton ,but with more customisation.
This is working for me.

DTGlowingLabel.h

```
 @interface DTGlowingLabel : UILabel {
 }

 @end
```

DTGlowingLabel.m

```
 #import "DTGlowingLabel.h"

 @implementation DTGlowingLabel

 - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIColor *insideColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:69.0/255.0 green:254.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1];
UIColor *outlineColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:22.0/255.0 green:145.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:0.8];
UIColor *blurColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:104.0/255.0 green: 248.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:0.7];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, outlineColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, insideColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, self.font.pointSize/60.0);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0, 0), self.font.pointSize / 10.0, blurColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFillStroke);

[self.text drawInRect:self.bounds withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode alignment:self.textAlignment];

 }

 @end
```

Source : http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/01/uilabels-with-neon-effect/